# Visual Studio from the command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-line, cl.exe

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a small c++ executable. Since I now want to use a different editor I have to call **cl.exe** and link.exe from the command line.

It is great that VS provides the used command-lines in  `Project->Properties->C/C++->Commandline`  and  `->Linker->CommandLine`
however, they dont work quite like they should:

In the compiler command line I added `/c` and removed the file-renaming-stuff `/Fp /Fa /Fo /Fd`  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx)

In the linker command line I removed the `/MANIFEST` and `/Manifest`
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx)

the result is this:

```
cl.exe main.cpp /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- 
    /O1 /Oi /Os /Oy /GL 
    /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" 
    /Gm- /EHsc /GS /Gy /fp:precise 
    /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue 


link.exe *.obj /OUT:"test2.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO 
    "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" 
    "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" 
    "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" 
    /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" 
    /DEBUG /PDB:"F:\prj\visualstudio2010\test2\Release\test2.pdb" 
    /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF 
    /PGD:"F:\prj\visualstudio2010\test2\Release\test2.pgd" 
    /LTCG /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

The resulting exe works the same way as if i had built it using the GUI, but **the problem is that it is 145kb instead of 22kb** for some reason. Should I just accept that or is there something obvious that the GUI has and that I am missing?

Comment: You can see full build log, including command line switches, in the project output directory, <program name>.log file. You can also build the project from command line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee0c8y7.aspx

Comment: You don't seem to have /MT nor /MD compiler switches. Could it be that you link to CRT DLL in one case, and to static CRT in the other? I'm not sure which one is used when no switch is provided.

Comment: @AlexFarber I will take a look if it is different

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried /MT and /MD and both but no change in output-size.

Comment: @AlexFarber using what was in that logfile and doing the same modifications i did before works! please add your comment as answer for me to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see full build log, including command line switches, in the project output directory, `program_name.log` file. You can also build the project from command line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee0c8y7.aspx

Comment: for future reference: It works if I take the command lines from the log-file (Alex) and apply the modifications (I wrote in my question).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to manually reproducing the individual command line args you can use msbuild.exe to build an entire solution from the command line:

On my machine the command would look like the following:

```
"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /t:Build /verbosity:minimal /maxcpucount /p:Configuration=Debug;Platform="x64" "C:\path\to\some_sln.sln"
```

Full documentation on msbuild can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx).

I would try running that and see if you're getting the exe size you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's something the original poster apparently figured out on their own but a critical part of running Visual Studio tools from the command line is to run the following batch file to set your environment variables correctly.  Otherwise, you will get an error about missing DLLs, and so on.  (This is Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7, but other combinations may be quite similar.)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat

which simply runs:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat

Answer (score 0):

You can compile a C++ project from a command line or .bat file. This works for VS2019:

```
rem path to Visual studio. No quotation marks:
set vspath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
rem path to vcvars files 
set batpath=%vspath%\VC\Auxiliary\Build
rem set system path
path %batpath%;%path%
rem set all paths and include directories for 64-bit mode compilation
call vcvars64.bat x64
rem compile:
cl [options] test.cpp /Fetest.exe
rem pause to see if compilation succeeds
pause
rem run the compiled program
test.exe
pause
```